# Why am I not able to create a tenant within Azure AD free account

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to create a tenant within Azure AD on my free account, in order to put some users there and connect to a backend project. But I cant create a tenant at all, when I go to the manage tenants, the create tenant button is not clickable at all.

p.s Also when entering Azure AD a have no primary domain(I tried to enter a custom domain the button is not clickable too) if this is a relevant factor to above issue.

Need a bit help on this issue, thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Could you include what **directory** roles you currently have on your tenant?

Comment: @Sridevi when I go to manage tenants, I have no tenant there, there's message "No tenants found".

Comment: @Sridevi Cited "Tenants in Azure AD are usually associated with an organization or a company. If you are an individual user with a free Azure account, you might not be able to create a new tenant directly from the Azure portal. Tenants are usually created when an organization signs up for Azure services and associates their Azure AD with their subscription."  if this is true, I have entered azure AD with my free acc and I think that's the problem, what do you think?

Comment: Do you mean `Free trial` subscription when you say Free account?

Comment: No I don't have subscription, I only signed up with my hotmail within azure.

Comment: Microsoft no more offers additional EntraID teanant to those with free EntraID tenant. Microsoft is now limiting this functionality to only paid customers. You can sign up for [Microsoft 365 Developer Program](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/dev-program) for a free sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

**This is by design** output if you do not have a subscription attached. I get the same result, **if I connect** with a dummy-test gmail (or any email) **account hat is not associated with an Azure subscription**, the "Create tenant" button is grayed out on my end too, and I do not see any existing tenants listed also, which is as I said expected.
[picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2gQ6.png)

*If you do not have an Azure subscription associated with your email account, you won't have any tenants listed in the Azure portal, and the "Create tenant" button will be disabled [Gray Out]*
--> This behavior is expected because an **Azure AD tenant is provisioned as a part of the Azure subscription** setup process.

`Azure AD tenants are created and associated with Azure subscriptions.`
When you sign up for an Azure subscription using your hotmail account or any other valid email address, a new Azure AD tenant is automatically created, and you become the Global Administrator for that tenant. `This process happens during the Azure subscription registration.`

To create a new Azure AD tenant and associate it with an Azure subscription, you should sign up for a new Azure subscription using your Gmail account or any other email address that you want to use for the Azure AD tenant.

**What if you had a Subscription but the button is still Gray Out?**

Ensure that you do not have enabled in Azure Active Directory `Restrict non-admin users from creating tenants`

Steps:

1. Go in AAD
2. Click on Users from the menu
3. Click on Users | User settings
4. Check Default user role permissions and see if Restrict non-admin users from creating tenants is on NO

PS: You can create tenants as a normal user on your personal Free/Paid subscription. If it's your personal subs you will also bu an AD admin by default, so more power to you.

By the way, to create and manage Azure resources, you will need to sign up for an Azure subscription
[You can select a free trial one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f80Ea.png)

You can check the Official Microsoft Documentation [Create a new tenant in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/create-new-tenant) and see that they mention to create a free account if do not have a subscription. When they say a free account, they mean that you should have at least a free trial subscription, not to connect to azure portal with your mail and nothing more. [mentioning here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99UU7.png)